# What does the ST_Union of the geometry column of two tables produce?

Tags: postgis, union

I'm working in Postgres 9.5. I have two tables, each with a column `geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)`.

I want to creat a single MultiPolygon that is the union of every polygon in the two tables.

I have tried running `ST_Union`, but it isn't doing quite what I expected. If I do this:

```
SELECT
ST_GeometryType(ST_Union(table1.geom, table2.geom))
FROM table1, table2;
```

This produces lots of `MultiPolygon` results, instead of a single one, which suggests to me that the result of a simple `ST_Union` is not a single polygon.

What is `ST_Union(table1.geom, table2.geom)` actually giving me, conceptually? Why are there multiple polygons?

What do I need to do to get a single multipolygon - something like `ST_Union(ST_Union(table1.geom), ST_Union(table2.geom))`?

Comment: Have you tried using ST_Multi  and/or ST_Collect around ST_Union. ST_Union will only union intersecting polygons. You are getting multiple (multipolygons) because each row represents those that actually form an intersecting union. ST_Collect simply concatenates unions, but if you perform this after ST_Union, you should get what you want, which will be one giant multipolygon.

Comment: Thanks! I see - I think. So perhaps I should do `ST_Union(ST_Collect(t1.geom), ST_Collect(t2.geom))` instead, for efficiency?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm half asleep, do as tumasgiu says.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

St_Union comes in two flavors, aggregate and simple.

In your query you are using the simple one that is creating the union of **two single** geometries.

What you are doing is cross joining your two tables, and make union of every combination of the geometries of your two tables, resulting in `n*m` multipolygons, where **n** is the row count of your first table and **m** the count of the second one.
This is called a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

To accomplish what you want, you need to use the aggregate version, that will behave like the sql-standard sum function. Something like :

```
SELECT st_union(geom) FROM (SELECT geom FROM table1 UNION SELECT geom FROM table2) as foo
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That does indeed return a single giant MultiPolygon. As a relative noob I'd like to understand a bit more about what I was doing wrong: was my error a SQL one, or to do with how [ST_Union](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) works? i.e. was the Cartesian product a function of the SQL query, or ST_Union?

Comment: I think it's about SQL : if the geometries were integers, ask yourself how can you sum the values of your two tables. It's the same idea.
You are misunderstanding what the FROM clause of your query is doing, that is : cross joining, i.e. create a new set from the combination of the elements of two other sets.
You also probably don't undestand what an aggegate function is.

Comment: great answer, I was never fully able to put into the words the two ways st_union can be utilized

Comment: Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) about aggregate function :
_In database management an aggregate function is a function where the values of multiple rows are grouped together as input on certain criteria to form a single value of more significant meaning or measurement such as a set, a bag or a list._